# How can I combine these 2 JavaScript functions (text masking/jQuery keyboard) for 1 text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this this text masking function:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maskedinput.js" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#answer246687X4X7").mask("(999) 999-9999",{placeholder:"#"});
        });
</script>
```

With this onscreen keyboard:

https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
         $("#answer246687X4X7").keyboard({
                    enterNavigation : true,
                    maxLength : 10,
                    usePreview : true,
                    reposition : true,
                    at2: 'center bottom',
                    layout : 'num'
                 });
</script>
```

How can I combine the two?

I am trying to use the text masking function on both the text area field in the form, which is identified by the **#answer246687X4X7** and in the preview input area of the jQuery keyboard window that appears when the form field has focus.

Comment: Have you tried calling both?

Comment: Hard to answer since you're not even really telling us what plugins you're using (there are dozens of masked input plugins for example). Secondly, what have you tried? What's not working? What is happening?

Comment: Also, that first `<script>` block should not have the `src` attribute if you have code between the `<script>` tags. You need to split it into two blocks  like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maskedinput.js" charset="utf-8"></script><script>/* Your code here */</script>`

Comment: @Andrew Yes and when I do, the keypad appears as it should, but when clicking the buttons, entered characters appear twice for each click, and the masking function does not work at all.

Comment: @Andrew Okay, now after removing the **src** tag and pre-pending the other two blocks of code, I got the mask to appear in the preview field for the on screen keyboard, but the mask doesn't actually work- it just shows the placeholder and just flashes when clicking on the on screen keys. Any ideas? Thanks again.